# getting photo from camera activity and display on the mainactivity, android

Tags: android, android-camera

I wanted to create my own camera app. the main activity has a button that when clicked, it will go to a camera activity( with a preview and a "take" button). Once i press the "take" button, the pictures will be taken. the taken pictures will return to the main activity and show on an image view. 
the problem is, I have no idea how to pass the photo from the camera activity back to main activity. Hope anyone could give a hint or example?

Answer (score 0):

Send intent to camera screen with a path. The Image will be captured & stored on that path.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
           if (!APP_FILE_PATH_Media.exists()) 
          {
               APP_FILE_PATH_Media.mkdirs();
          }
         uriSavedImage =new File(APP_FILE_PATH_Media+ "/" +
                    "IMG_"+ getTimeStamp() + ".jpeg");
       cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(uriSavedImage));
       startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Now when you click take it will call onActivityResult method of your main Activity.
In OnActivityResult:

```
path=uriSavedImage.getAbsolutePath();
```

You can use this path for displaying the image.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed! you have to send Camera intent with `startActivityForResult`, have a look below sort of code:

Define path where you want to store your image:

```
 String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foldername/"+filename;
 File file = new File(_path);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

*Camera Intent*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1212);
```

*Override startActivityForResult*

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == 1212) {
            //here you can decode your path and use for displaying an image. 
        }
    }
```

Comment: But I don't want to use the inbuilt camera app. How am i going to call my own camera activity( with liveview/preview and a "take" button)

how am i going to call my own camera activity while passing the intent?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please have a try with this code.

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 



    static String str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath = "";
    private static File f;
    private static int Take_Photo = 2;
    private static String str_randomnumber = "";
    static String str_Camera_Photo_ImageName = "";
    public static String str_SaveFolderName;
    private static File wallpaperDirectory;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    int storeposition = 0;
    public static GridView gridview;
    public static ImageView imageView;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ccccc);
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                str_SaveFolderName = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath()
                        + "/rajeshsample";
                str_randomnumber = String.valueOf(nextSessionId());
                wallpaperDirectory = new File(str_SaveFolderName);
                if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists())
                    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
                str_Camera_Photo_ImageName = str_randomnumber
                        + ".jpg";
                str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath = str_SaveFolderName
                        + "/" + str_randomnumber + ".jpg";
                System.err.println(" str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath  "
                        + str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath);
                f = new File(str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath);
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).putExtra(
                        MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f)),
                        Take_Photo);
                System.err.println("f  " + f);
            }
        });
    }


    // used to create randon numbers
    public String nextSessionId() {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TTTTTTTTTTTT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == Take_Photo) {
            String filePath = null;

            filePath = str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath;
            if (filePath != null) {
                Bitmap faceView = ( new_decode(new File(
                                filePath))); // ========================> good
                                                // lines



                imageView.setImageBitmap(faceView);

            } else {
                bitmap = null;
            }
        }
    } 

    public static Bitmap new_decode(File f) {

        // decode image size

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inDither = false; // Disable Dithering mode

        o.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory,
                                // the Bitmap can be cleared

        o.inInputShareable = true; // Which kind of reference will be used to
                                    // recover the Bitmap data after being
                                    // clear, when it will be used in the future
        try {
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 300;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 1.5 < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp / 1.5 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 1.5;
            height_tmp /= 1.5;
            scale *= 1.5;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        // o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        o.inDither = false; // Disable Dithering mode

        o.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory,
                                // the Bitmap can be cleared

        o.inInputShareable = true; // Which kind of reference will be used to
                                    // recover the Bitmap data after being
                                    // clear, when it will be used in the future
        // return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        try {

//          return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null,
//                  null);
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null);
            System.out.println(" IW " + width_tmp);
            System.out.println("IHH " + height_tmp);           
               int iW = width_tmp;
                int iH = height_tmp;

               return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, iW, iH, true);

        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            // clearCache();

            // System.out.println("bitmap creating success");
            System.gc();
            return null;
            // System.runFinalization();
            // Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
            // System.gc();
            // decodeFile(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code on button click event

```
    Intent action = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
 action.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
startActivityForResult(action,TAKE_PICTURE_FROM_CAMERA);
```

you have to use

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

}

if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                uri = data.getData();
                try {
                    photoBitMap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    int h = 100; // height in pixels
                    int w = 100; // width in pixels
                    photoBitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photoBitMap, h, w,
                            true);

                    uri = Uri.parse(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                            .insertImage(getContentResolver(), photoBitMap,
                                    null, null));
                    Bitmap usableBMP = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photoBitMap,
                            68, 80, true);

                    if (!Calculations.encodeImageToBase64(photoBitMap).equals(
                            "")
                            && Calculations.encodeImageToBase64(photoBitMap) != null) {
                        // userPhoto.setImageBitmap(usableBMP);
                        userPhoto.setImageBitmap(Calculations
                                .getRoundedCornerBitmap(this, usableBMP));

                    } else {
                        userPhoto.setImageBitmap(null);
                        userPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_user_img);
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,
                                getString(R.string.imageSizeValidation),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    userPhoto.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,
                            getString(R.string.imageSizeValidation),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```